# WordPress Widget Radio Buttons not saving → Only with PHP no Js/JQuery

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Here is the Full code of the Widget →

```
        <p> <input type="radio" <?php checked(  $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ], 'check_for_counter' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_counter' ); ?>" value="check_for_counter" name="what_to_check_for" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_counter' ); ?>">Check whether to display description or not</label> </p>

        <p> <input type="radio" <?php checked( $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ], 'check_for_image' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_image' ); ?>" value="check_for_image" name="what_to_check_for" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_image' ); ?>">Select to Post with Thumbnails</label> </p>
```

## The Problem →

the problem is that the radio button is not saving. I am attaching a Video recording below for this.
the radio button not getting saved → https://www.screencast.com/t/pLad8AwrOXiS

> Please guide me where I am going wrong. Is `isset` missing for this
>   radio button? If yes, then help me finish that.

Comment: Is there no one to help me?

Comment: did you try with js?

Comment: thanks for asking, but I don't know Js, and I know this could be achieved with PHP

Comment: `what_to_check_for` value not posting..

Comment: Thanks, so what will be the solution within the limit of PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Its working.

```
            <p> <input type="radio" class="what_to_check_for" <?php  checked($what_to_check_for ,'check_for_counter'); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_counter' ); ?>" value="check_for_counter" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'what_to_check_for' ); ?>" >
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_counter' ); ?>">Check whether to display description or not</label> </p>

            <p> <input type="radio" class="what_to_check_for" <?php checked($what_to_check_for ,'check_for_image'); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_image' ); ?>" value="check_for_image" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'what_to_check_for' ); ?>" >
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'check_for_image' ); ?>">Select to Post with Thumbnails</label> </p>
```

Comment: Please update your answer w/o JS/JQuery, but only PHP or delete the solution.

Comment: js removed. Please check and let me know

Comment: Due to some code privacy issue I have to delete the question. Can I humbly request you sir to please delete the answer so that I can delete the question sir?

Comment: I have edited mine and your code also. Please accept the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151798/discussion-between-adiyogi-and-vel).