# Radio Button value dilemma

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

```
$instance['what_to_check_for']   = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['what_to_check_for']);
```

Now I a trying to do something through ternary operators →

```
$description_radio_box = $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ] ? 'check_for_counter' : 'check_for_image';
```

basically I am trying to find a condition →

```
<?php if( $description_radio_box == 'check_for_counter' ){ ?>
```

or

```
                <?php if( $description_radio_box == 'check_for_image' )
```

Is my approach correct or I am misisng something because the two above conditions doesnt work?

[related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648589/wordpress-widget-radio-buttons-not-saving-%E2%86%92-only-with-php-no-js-jquery)

Comment: Where is the condition in ternary operator? What you are trying to achieve. Your question is not clear

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to do, but here's your ternary explained:
    
    `$description_radio_box = $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ] ? 'check_for_counter' : 'check_for_image';`

If `$instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ]` evaluates to true (http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), `$description_radio_box` will be assigned the value `'check_for_counter'`. Otherwise `$description_radio_box` will be assigned the value `'check_for_image'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add ternary operators for assign value. As your radio buttons it self containing value like `check_for_counter` or `check_for_image`. Simply assign radio button value to `$description_radio_box`

change

```
$description_radio_box = $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ] ? 'check_for_counter' : 'check_for_image';
```

To

```
$description_radio_box = $instance[ 'what_to_check_for' ];
```